# Proving that a given function defines an inner product with a constraint?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have to prove that $<x|y> = 5x_1 y_1+ 3x_2y_2+t(x_1y_2+x_2y_1)$ but only when $|t| > \sqrt{15}$. I have proved all conditions for defining an inner product except for positivity, defined as $<x|x>\;>0 $ with $x\neq0$.

I was given the hint to try $(x_1,x_2) = \rho(cos\theta sin\theta)$ but the notation confused me (I assumed $(x_1,x_2)$ meant $x_1x_2$) but even then I can't see how that would be useful here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner product can be written as $x^\top A y$ where $A = \begin{bmatrix}5 & t \\ t & 3\end{bmatrix}$ and $x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}$ and $y = \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix}$.

Thus, you want to check $x^\top A x > 0$ for all $x \ne 0$. This is equivalent to $A$ having positive eigenvalues. Write down the eigenvalues of $A$ in terms of $t$ and you will find your condition.

---

If you want to follow the hint:

The hint should be $(x_1, x_2) = \rho (\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$.
(Here, $\rho = \sqrt{x_1^2+ x_2^2}$ and $\theta = \arctan(x_2/x_1)$.

Then $$\langle x \mid x \rangle = 5 \rho^2 \cos^2 \theta + 3 \rho^2 \sin^2 \theta + 2 t \rho^2 \cos \theta \sin \theta = \rho^2 (\sqrt{5} \cos \theta + \sqrt{3} \sin \theta)^2 - 2\rho^2(\sqrt{15} - t) \cos \theta \sin \theta.$$
How do you choose $t$ such that this is positive for any $\rho$ and $\theta$?